# How do I find the intersection of lists of lists in R?

Tags: r

Say I have three lists,

```
> a
[[1]]
     begin end
     3     5
     9     10
     11    14

[[2]]
     begin end
     3     7
     14    18
     19    24

[[3]]
     begin end
     6     9
     14    22
     18    30
```

What I am trying to find is the intersection of all of the "begin" columns, so in this case the desired output would be something like

```
"3" "14"
```

I am aware of the solution offered at [How to find common elements from multiple vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695677/how-to-find-common-elements-from-multiple-vectors); however, this solution assumes that the number of lists is static.  If the number of lists I have here were to change (say, to 5 lists, each one with similar columnar layout), how would I find the intersection?

Comment: `a[[1]]` does not have 14 in `begin`. Should the code consider both `begin` and `end`?

Comment: Good question.  The answer is no, as I want ANY intersection.  So if at least two lists share a similar element in begin, this should be found.

Comment: The problem with using rbind here is that I need to keep the lists separate.  After this step in the program I need to determine the frequency of elements in each list with respect to those that are in the intersected set.  so for example, if [[3]]'s begin column contained 3,3,7, then the program would show that the frequency of 3 in list 1 is 1, 3 in list 2 is 1, and 3 in list 3 is 2.

Comment: `Reduce(function(x, y) intersect(x, y), lapply(a, '[[', 'begin'))` note that this wont work for your example because your example has no values common to all begin columns

Comment: @rawr They're misusing the concept of "intersection of all x" and really want "appears in some pairwise intersection among x"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @nico's input data...

```
full <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(a), function(i) within(a[[i]], {g = i})) )

res  <- table(full[,c("begin","g")])

#      g
# begin 1 2 3
#    3  1 1 0
#    6  0 0 1
#    9  1 0 0
#    11 1 0 0
#    14 0 1 1
#    18 0 0 1
#    19 0 1 0
```

The rows are the unique values of `begin` and the columns are the elements of the list. To see which values of `begin` appear in more than one element of the list, look at

```
res[ rowSums( res>0 ) > 1, ]
#      g
# begin 1 2 3
#    3  1 1 0
#    14 0 1 1
```

Probably whatever further analysis you have to do should be done on `full` rather than on your list of data.frames, especially if efficiency is a concern.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to collapse the list elements and use `table` to count them

```
# Recreate the data frame
a <- list(
    data.frame(begin = c(3, 9, 11), end = c(5, 10, 14)),
    data.frame(begin = c(3, 14, 19), end = c(7, 18, 24)),
    data.frame(begin = c(6, 14, 18), end = c(9, 22, 30)))

# "Collapse" the begin columns into a vector.
# We use unlist in case the data frames are not all 
# of the same length(thanks @Frank for pointing this out)
a.beg <- unlist(sapply(a, function(x){x$begin}))

# Count the elements
tb <- table(a.beg)

# Get the ones repeated at least twice 
# (need to cast to numeric as names are strings)
intersection <- as.numeric(names(tb[tb>=2]))

> intersection
[1]  3 14
```

Comment: This is not scaleable!

Comment: @rdevn00b is scaleable for any number of elements in a... how do you want it scaleable?

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I have to manually enter all data frames in order to use it.  In the case of a dynamic number of data frames this solution will not hold.

Comment: @rdevn00b You do not have to manually enter the data.frames. nico was just trying to recreate your example data. Anywho, fyi, I am deleting my comments after they're resolved (as is customary here, to "clean up" unnecessary chatter).

Comment: @rdevn00b I am assuming you'll get your data from some source (csv file, database, somewhere on the Internet) using `read.table` or similar functions.