# R: how to find common elements with the same indices in multiple vectors

Tags: r, vector

My question is somewhat similar to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695677/how-to-find-common-elements-from-multiple-vectors](http://this) question. Suppose I have 3 vectors all of the same length:

```
v1 <- c(1, 99, 10, 11, 23)
v2 <- c(1, 99, 10, 23, 11)
v3 <- c(2, 4, 10, 13, 23)
```

Comparing v1 and v2:

It's easy to see that `v1` and `v2` have the same elements, which would be returned by `Reduce(intersect, list(v1, v2))`. However, I only want the overlap to be returned ONLY if their order in the vectors are the same as well. Therefore, I would only want to see `1 99 10` because they're both ordered as indices 1, 2, 3, respectively.

Comparing v1 and v3:
Here, `10 23` should be returned.

Comparing v2 and v3:
Only `10` should be returned.
In order to handle pairwise comparisons, I think I'll use a nested loop:

```
v_all = list(v1, v2, v3)
length_v = length(v_all) - 1
for(i in 1:length_v){
  v_ind = 1:length(v_all)
  v_2 = v_ind[-which(v_all == i)]
  for(j in v_2){
    #code for finding overlap
  }
}
```

Comment: You can find the overlap of two vectors with `overlap <- function(x,y){x[x==y]}`

Comment: `length_v` seems to be 14 in your example.  Is that deliberate?

Comment: @Henry Thanks for pointing that out. I changed `v_all` to a list. So `length_v` should be 2, which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this using a simple comparison check:

```
x == y
```

and subsetting x by it: `x[x==y]`. Then the question is how to best loop it over the combinations.

Here, I'll use `outer` to take the all by all output of each combination of the list of vectors, and call a Vectorized anonymous function on it.

```
v1 <- c(1, 99, 10, 11, 23)
v2 <- c(1, 99, 10, 23, 11)
v3 <- c(2, 4, 10, 13, 23)

l = list(v1,v2,v3)


outer(l,l,Vectorize(function(x,y){x[x==y]}))

     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] Numeric,5 Numeric,3 Numeric,2
[2,] Numeric,3 Numeric,5 10       
[3,] Numeric,2 10        Numeric,5
```

if you look in the output matrix, each cell is the overlap of the indexed lists:

```
output[1,2]
[[1]]
[1]  1 99 10
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a quick way to see which `i, j` cell (s) has a list that has > 1 but < 5 elements?