# Finding shared elements in at least n of m vectors (n < m)

Tags: r

```
lists <- lapply(vector("list", 5), function(x) sample(1:100,50,replace=T))
```

How can i extract all values which are present in at least n (2,3,4,5) vectors inside `lists` (or generally in a population of vectors)?
For n=5, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695677/how-to-find-common-elements-from-multiple-vectors) gives already a solution (e.g. `intersect()`), but is unclear to me for cases of n < m.
In this particular case, i perform 5 variants of mean-comparisons between two groups, and want to extract a consensus between the 5 tests (e.g. significantly different in at least 3 tests).

Comment: Can't you just use `unique` and `table`? For example: `n <- 5; table(unlist(lapply(lists, unique))) >= n`

Comment: You mean `Reduce(intersect, lists[2:5])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do it as follows. Assume that you are interested in values that are shared between at least 3 list elements.

```
combos <- combn(seq_along(lists), 3, simplify = FALSE)
lapply(combos, function(i) Reduce(intersect, lists[i]))
```

And if you're just interested in the actual values,

```
unique(unlist(lapply(combos, function(i) Reduce(intersect, lists[i]))))
```

In `combos` we store all possible combinations of your lists of length n (here, 3).

Comment: The line starting with "unique" is what i wanted. This should give me the values which appear in at least 3 of the 5 list elements, correct?

Comment: You can also do it all  inside `combn`, i.e. `combn(seq_along(lists), 3, simplify = FALSE, FUN = function(i) Reduce(intersect, lists[i]))`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply reduce lists using `unique` then combine them into one vector with `unlist` and count with `table`.

```
n <- 3
names(which(table(unlist(lapply(lists, unique))) >= n))
```

Output of this code is vector of names.