# Cross-tabulation of shared elements between several vectors

Tags: r, set, intersection

I'm trying and failing to get the number of elements in the intersect between several vectors at once in R: I have several character vectors of different lengths (unique elements) and want to get the number of elements shared between each pair of vectors.

Essentially, this means something like `length(intersect(a,b))`, but repeated several times/as a cross-tabulation over all combinations of vectors.

I feel like this is a simple case involving something like the `apply()` family, but I can't seem to figure this out... :-/

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Maybe this is what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695677/how-to-find-common-elements-from-multiple-vectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the intersection of all combinations of vectors you can do:

```
l <- list(a1 = 1:5, a2 = 3:6, a3 = 4:9)

intsct_list <- combn(seq_along(l), 2, function(x) intersect(l[[x[1]]], l[[x[2]]]), simplify = FALSE)

names(intsct_list) <- combn(names(l), 2, paste0, collapse = "")

lengths(intsct_list)  

a1a2 a1a3 a2a3 
   3    2    3
```

Comment: Thank you so much; this is exactly what I was looking for!
(Sorry, however, for being so very late to respond!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Reduce`; here is a minimal reproducible example

```
a1 <- 1:5
a2 <- 3:6
a3 <- 4:9

Reduce(intersect, list(a1, a2, a3))
#[1] 4 5
```

The key is to store the vectors in a `list`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had already tried the Reduce function but could not get the length function to work on that.