# How to Combine Variables in R with no repetition

Tags: r, data-structures

I Have three vectors. Each vector stating list of participants have that disease.

```
A.Cancer= c(Part1,Part2,Part3,Part4)
B.Cancer= c(Part3,Part2,Part5,Part6)
C.Cancer=c(Part1,Part7,Part8,Part9,Part10)
```

I want to combine them in a way that no repetition.I want output like.

```
Cancer_Disease=(Part1,Part2,Part3,Part4,Part5,Part6,Part7,Part8,Part9,Part10)
```

How to do this in R?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/3695677/680068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union`

```
a <- 1:10
b <- 5:15
c <- 12:20

Reduce(union, list(a, b, c))
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Answer (score 4):

Note: I don't think the code you've listed will actually run, since you'd need quotation marks around the `Part1` etc. terms (unless those are objects that have already been stored in memory somewhere else in your code).

That said: you can do this in `base` R with `c()` and `unique()`:

```
Cancer_Disease <- unique(c(A.Cancer, B.Cancer, C.Cancer))
```

Putting the vectors in `c()` will string them together, and `unique()` will remove the repetitions.

Answer (score 1):

Using `reduce` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
list(a, b, c) %>%
    reduce(union)
```

#### data

```
a <- 1:10
b <- 5:15
c <- 12:20
```