# Compare two objects then return matching values only

Tags: r

I have been able to use `which()` to extract data from two individual columns based on a given criteria:

```
# cars with 6 cylinders
cyl_6 <- which(mtcars$cyl == 6)

# cars with 4 gears
gear_4 <- which(mtcars$gear == 4)
```

Respectively these return:

```
> cyl_6
[1]  1  2  4  6 10 11 30
> gear_4
[1]  1  2  3  8  9 10 11 18 19 20 26 32
```

How can I compare these two objects to get the common values into a new object? I'm expecting the outcome to be:

```
> cyl_6_gear_4
[1] 1 2 10 11
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find common elements from multiple vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695677/how-to-find-common-elements-from-multiple-vectors)

Comment: Yes, thank you!.. I was searching 'objects' not 'vectors'. Still kinda new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retain possible duplicates, you can use `%in%`

```
subset(cyl_6, cyl_6 %in% gear_4)
```

Otherwise, a simpler one might be `intersect`

```
intersect(cyl_6, gear_4)
```

Answer (score 1):

`intersect()` will get what you need

```
intersect(cyl_6, gear_4)
```

```
[1]  1  2 10 11
```